universal quotient of tensor algebra
For a unital algebra $A$, and a two-sided ideal $I$ of $A \otimes A$, does there exists a universal quotient algebra $B$ of $A$, with map $q: A \twoheadrightarrow B$, such that $q \otimes q: A \otimes A \twoheadrightarrow B \otimes B$ factors through $(A \otimes A)/I$?
i.e. if there exists another quotient algebra $C$ of $A$ such the map $f: A \otimes A \twoheadrightarrow C \otimes C$ factors through $(A \otimes A)/I$, then the map $A \to C$ factors through $q$?

I assume you mean algebras over a field?

The answer is "not always". Below, I will give two explicit counterexamples and two explicit examples, and afterwards (this will be the main part) give a general criterion for the existence of this universal quotient. I assume that we work with algebras over a field $K$. This ensures that the tensor product over $K$ preserves monomorphisms.
Examples
a) When $I = 0$, the quotient exists and is just $A$.
b) When $A = K[X]$ and $I = \langle X \otimes X \rangle $ the universal quotient does exist: It is the universal $K$-algebra generated by an element $a$ such that $a \otimes a = 0$. This is equivalent to $a = 0$. So the answer is $K$ with $a=0$.
Counterexamples
a) Let $A = K[X,Y]$ and $I = \langle X \otimes Y \rangle \subseteq A \otimes A$. Here the universal quotient would be a universal $K$-algebra $B$ generated by two commuting elements $x,y \in B$ with $x \otimes y = 0$ in $B \otimes B$. We must have $x \neq 0$, witnessed by the (non-universal) example $1 \otimes 0 = 0$ in $K \otimes K$. Similarly, we must have $y \neq 0$. But linear algebra tells us that $x,y \neq 0$ implies $x \otimes y \neq 0$, a contradiction.
b) Let $A = K[X]$ and $I = \langle X \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes X \rangle$. The universal quotient would be a universal $K$-algebra $B$ generated by an element $x$ satisfying $x \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes x$. By considering $1 \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes 1$ in $K \otimes K$, we see $x \neq 0$ and $1 \neq 0$ in $B$. Therefore, $x \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes x$ means $x = \lambda 1$ for some $\lambda \in K^*$, but $\lambda$ cannot be chosen universally (unless $K = \mathbb{F}_2$ of course, in which case $K$ with $1 \in K$ is the universal quotient).
General criterion
Assume that a universal quotient $q : A \twoheadrightarrow B$ exists for an ideal $I \subseteq A \otimes A$. The first step is to show that the universal property, initially stated only for surjective homomorphisms $A \to C$, actually holds for all homomorphisms of algebras.
Let $f : A \to C$ be any algebra homomorphism such that $f \otimes f  : A \otimes A \to C \otimes C$ vanishes on $I$, we need to show that $f$ factors uniquely through $q$. Uniqueness is clear since $q$ is assumed to be surjective. Existence is clear by assumption when $f$ is surjective, but if $f$ is not surjective, consider the image decomposition of $f$ as $f' : A \twoheadrightarrow C'$ followed by $i : C' \hookrightarrow C$. Since $i \otimes i$ is injective, then $f' \otimes f'$ vanishes on $I$. Hence, $f'$ factors through $q$. And this shows that also $f$ factors through $q$.
As always, this universal property can also be stated in terms of a representable functor. Here, we consider the functor $F_I : \mathbf{Alg}_k \to \mathbf{Set}$, a subfunctor of $\hom(A,-)$ actually, that maps an algebra $C$ to the set of homomorphisms $f : A \to C$ such that $f \otimes f$ vanishes on $I$. By what we saw above, $F_I$ is representable if $q$ exists. The converse is also true, since it can be checked that every representing object $A \to B$ of $F_I$ must be surjective.
Every representable functor preserves all limits, and by Freyd's representability criterion, the converse is also true in our case, since the (regular) quotients of $A$ provide a solution set for $F_I$. So we should analyse the condition that $F_I$ preserves all limits, or equivalently, equalizers and products (see here for the equivalence). But by a similar argument as above it is easy to check that $F_I$ preserves equalizers anyway.
Hence, a universal quotient exists for $I$ if and only if $F_I$ preserves products. This means that for a family of homomorphisms $(f_i : A \to C_i)_{i \in I}$, if each $f_i \otimes f_i : A \otimes A \to C_i \otimes C_i$ vanishes on $I$, then $f \otimes f : A \otimes A \to \prod_{i \in I} C_i \otimes \prod_{i \in I} C_i$ vanishes on $I$, where $f : A \to \prod_{i \in I} C_i$ is the homomorphism induced by $f_i$.
The natural map $\prod_{i \in I} C_i \otimes \prod_{i \in I} C_i \to \prod_{i,j \in I} C_i \otimes C_j$ is injective (since we are working over a field). Therefore, $f \otimes f$ vanishes on $I$ if and only if each $f_i \otimes f_j : A \otimes A \to C_i \otimes C_j$ vanishes on $I$.
So the condition reduces to: If two homomorphisms $f : A \to C$, $g : A \to C'$ are given such that $f \otimes f$ and $g \otimes g$ vanish on $I$, then also $f \otimes g$ has to vanish on $I$ (and by symmetry then also $g \otimes f$). Now, the kernel of $f \otimes g$ is equal to $\ker(f) \otimes A + A \otimes \ker(g)$, see here. Therefore:

General Criterion. The universal quotient exists for $I \subseteq A \otimes A$ if and only if for all ideals $J,J' \subseteq A$ with $I \subseteq J \otimes A + A \otimes J$ and $I \subseteq J' \otimes A + A \otimes J'$, we also have $I \subseteq J \otimes A + A \otimes J'$.

I am not sure if this condition can be simplified further.

Hi Martin, Thank you very much for your detailed answer! And thanks also for the very clear examples! Really helps

You are welcome! I believe that the quotient only exists in "uninteresting" cases, namely when the quotient collapses somehow. At least this is witnessed by the examples I gave. I wonder if the criterion I gave can be used to prove this.

Yes, it seems like most of the time this quotient will not exist. Moreover, it seems that the criterion you gave works where the k-algebras are just replaced with vector spaces over k

You mean given a subspace $U \subseteq V \otimes V$, we want a universal quotient vector space $q : V \to W$ such that $q \otimes q$ vanishes on $U$? I don't think that exists either always.

Yes, that is what I mean. I guess my question is whether your proof in the above actually requires the fact that we are dealing with algebras and algebra maps?
